# AWS-ECS Task Services restart automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

Currently we are running application with serverless architecture microservices using AWS ECS, whenever we deployed or update new artifacts on ECR, we need to restart the services by changing the tasks from 0 to 1 vice versa to restart the service and pick-up the new artifacts. As we know this process is very manual and taking some steps to accomplish, I want to automate this, is it possible to use AWS-lambda or cloudwatch? or any configuration as long as to skip the manual process. What kind of code and language and example of automation do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ecs-deploy](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy) script. Basically it will replace an existing service with a latest (or specific) image from ECR. So if you have automation to update ECR with the latest image this script will deploy that image to ECS

Answer (score 0):

A setup which could work if you have a CI/CD pipeline is upon uploading to ECR, trigger a lambda which resets that corresponding service. Supplying any variables to the lambda such as ECR tag to pull or service name.
ECS has an option to restart services with **ForceNewDeployment**. In Python the call would look like.

```
        updateTrigger = client.update_service(
        cluster = myClusterName,
        service = serviceToUpdate,
        desiredCount = 1,
        forceNewDeployment=True
    )
```

From https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.update_service